# Click on div inside of dynamically loaded <li> elements does not work

Tags: jquery, html, click, parent

I have an ordered list with dynamically loaded li elements. Each of these li contains a div. By clicking on this div, the li containing it should be deleted. I have given these divs a height and width of 24px.

The li look like this:

```
<li id="parent">Some text <div id="child"></div></li>
```

These are appended to the ol like this:

```
$('#id_of_ol').append('<li id="parent">Some text <div id="child"></div></li>');
```

Here is the jquery code that I have tried:

```
$('#child').on('click', function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Of course, this alert is just there to check whether it's working, I will replace that with remove() later.

However, this doesn't work. On clicking, nothing whatsoever happens. What's the problem here?

Comment: Do all the LI use the same `id="child"`? IDs need to be unique, you should use a class.

Comment: I have already tried that, that doesn't work either.

Comment: You used a class and event delegation as in the duplicate question?

Comment: Edit the question and show what you tried, and I'll reopen it.